# How to set attributes in monaco editor textarea?

Tags: monaco-editor

My question is about monaco editor and how to set the `name` attribute?
I've wrapped the editor in a `<form>` and I know there it is hidden `<textarea>` - I want to set some attributes.

**What is the best way to set attributes?**

Is there a configuration ?

The only way I found is to use this code, but it's a little hacking:
`$(editor.getDomNode()).find('textarea').attr('name', 'content');`

Full code example:

```js
var editor;
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/lib/monaco-editor/dist/min/vs' } });
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
    var editorOptions = {
        value: '<div> Hello World! </div>',
        language: 'html',

    };

    editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), editorOptions);

    // The only way to set name 
    $(editor.getDomNode()).find('textarea').attr('name', 'content');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `monaco editor` puts only a part of the visible content in the `<textarea>`. In that case, it will submit only part of the content. The best solution is to use another hidden `<textarea>` and set the actual content using `editor.getValue()` function kjust before submit the form.